# What is wrong with this code to plot '(y^2)/2-cos(x)'?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I want to contour plot the curves *(y^2)/2-cos(x)=c* with the following code, but there are only straight line in the output figure. What's wrong? Any help or suggestions will be appreciated!

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-10:10,view={0}{90}] 
\addplot3[contour gnuplot={number=15,labels=false},thick]  {(y^2)/2-cos(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: is it (y^2)/2 - cos(x) or y^(2/(2-cos(x))) or is it [1/(2-cos(x))]y^2

Comment: PGFPlots uses degrees, so your domain is too small.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PGFPlots uses degrees for trigonometric functions, not radians. You can convert your values to degrees using `deg(x)` instead of just `x`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-10:10,view={0}{90}, samples=60, samples y=60] 
\addplot3[contour gnuplot={number=15,labels=false},thick]  {(y^2)/2-cos(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what is the reason that I get with `xelatex` a completely other output? I have current TL 2013. My output: http://perce.de/pub/xelatex.png

Comment: @Herbert thanks for the helpful question. That is a bug; the input file for `gnuplot` receives `^^I` as column separator; but that does not seem to work in `xelatex` (which generates three separate chars). I will take care of it.

Comment: @Herbert I have fixed it in the developer version.